# Concatenate multiple ranges in a list

Tags: python

in python is there a way to create of list that will skip numbers and will continue after skipping? something like the following code:

```
x = [1...3, 6...10]
print(x)
# [1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Well its easy to write a for loop and then skip each defined index/value, or i can just use `range`, what I am looking for is a shorter more readable line. If not I can understand.

Comment: Python doesn't support *any* special range syntax, never mind implicit concatenation of such within the same list literal.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Alternatively you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(range(1, 5), range(20, 25)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Answer (score 23):

Simplest way to do this is to call [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) and [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) result inside list assignment.

```
x = [*range(1, 4), *range(6, 11)]
```

Comment: While this works, it's worth noting that this creates the entire list in memory. If you just want to iterate over the resulting sequence once, then this will consume more memory than the `itertools.chain` method. 40 bytes per number on my system, to be exact. This is fine for small sequences, but if your sequence has a billion numbers, well, you do the math...

Answer (score 9):

If `numpy` is an option, you can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to concatenate slice objects:

```
import numpy as np

np.r_[1:4, 6:11]
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it into a recursive function:

```
def recursive_ranges(ranges):
    if len(ranges) == 1:
        return list(range(*ranges[0]))
    else:
        return list(range(*ranges[0])) + recursive_ranges(ranges[1:])
```

You can then call this, specifying ranges as a list of lists:

```
ranges = [[1, 4], [6, 11]]
recursive_ranges(ranges)
# [1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Note the `*ranges[0]` is used to unpack the elements in `ranges[0]` into individual arguments. Essentially the recursive function keeps grabbing the first element of `ranges`, each element of which is a two-element array, and passing those numbers into the `range()` method as two different values instead of one array. That's what the `*` does, it unpacks the array. First call, you unpack `[1, 4]` into `range(1, 4)` and then append the next call of the recursive function to it.

Basically this unpacks into the following:

```
list(range(1, 4)) + list(range(6, 11))
```

but you get to use a much more compact syntax, just passing a list of lists.

Comment: this will be too long for larger numbers

Comment: @Led what do you mean? Also see my update with the recursive function. Pretty compact.

Comment: thanks, but there is a need to write a function. Great idea by the way