# Select two different intervals in a list (python)

Tags: python, list

I am trying to fit a dataset in which I want my fitting model to account for two different intervals of my data (i.e.: I want to fit two different regions of my dataset, let's the first 10 elements of a list and the 30 last ones).

To fit a specific interval within a list,I usually write the following:

```
p2, cov2 = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(scatter2,wv[0:121],ab[0:121],p0=p_guess2, absolute_sigma=True, maxfev=90000, method='lm') 
    a2, b2=p2
```

However, since I am looking to fit an extra region of data, I wanted to write in a pythonic way something of the following:

```
wv[0:121]+[461:481] #(I know this is not written properly)
```

What is then the proper way to call two different regions of a list?

Thank you in advance for all the help!

I have tried to google, but I am probably not googling the write terms to find the answer.
I have also just tried to do the fitting by calling my list as

```
wv[0:121][461:481]
```

, but this did not work either.

Comment: To get list consisting of first 10 elements (`wv[:10]`) and 30 last (`wv[-30:]`), just write `wv[:10] + wv[-30:]`

Comment: `wv[0:121] + wv[461:481]` will give you a list

Answer (score 0):

Think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55654889/concatenate-multiple-ranges-in-a-list) might have good options / approaches for your problem:

- Numpy np.r_

  ```
  import numpy as np
  np.r_[1:4, 6:11]
  #array([ 1,  2,  3,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
  ```
- itertools.chain function.

top rated is using range and unpack (* operator)

```
x = [*range(1, 4), *range(6, 11)]
```

but as mentioned in the comments this produces the list in memory. So if your actual list is rather small this might be ok. Otherwise [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) might be the better option.